# Mvx.MvxBindableListView in MvvmCross

Tags: mvvmcross

I am very new to MvvmCross.
To use Mvx.MvxBindableListView in my android Acivity, My activity should be inherited from 
which class ,whether from MvxActivity or other class ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct, your activity needs to inherit from MvxActivity. If you want to learn more about MvvmCross, I highly recommend watching N+1 series of videos http://mvvmcross.blogspot.com/